# Why is "le" used instead of "la" in "su marido le pegó"?

Tags: gramática, selección-de-palabras, verbos, objetos-indirectos, objetos-directos

In *A New Reference Grammar of Modern Spanish* (5th ed. 2013) by John Butt and Carmen Benjamin the following is seen:

> The passive must not be used when the subject of the passive sentence would be an indirect object: 'she was sent a letter' must be *le fue enviada una carta* or *le enviaron una carta* [...] Nor should the passive with *ser* be used when the object of the verb in the active sentence takes the third-person pronouns *le* or *les*. One can transform *su marido la abandonó* into *fue abondonada por su marido* 'she was deserted by her husband', but *su marido le pegó* 'her husband beat her' should not be transformed into *fue pegada por su marido*

My question is, why would 'le' be used at all in 'su marido le pegó'? Isn't 'her' (the wife) the direct object and thus, should not 'la' be used?

Answer (score 6):

There are verbs that can take the indirect object (*le / les*) without a direct one. For example:

- Verbs of emotion and mental process: *Le gustas mucho* (He/She likes you a lot)

Other verbs in this group are *encantar, agradar, parecer, asombrar, molestar, preocupar, interesar, extrañar, importar, enojar*

- Verbs related to ownership: *quedar, faltar, tocar, sobrar, pertenecer*

*Le quedan cuatro* (He has four left)

- Verbs related to size, duration and convenience: *quedar, convenir, durar, caber*

*Les queda bien* (It fits them well) / *Le conviene* (It suits him)

- Verbs where the direct object is implicit: *escribir, pegar, pagar, robar, contestar, ganar*

*Le escribí* (I wrote - a letter, an email - to him/her)

*Le pegué* (I hit him/her - I gave him a punch / a slap)

*Le pagué* (I paid him/her - an amount of money)

*Le robé* (I robbed him/her - of something)

*Le contesté* (I answered him/her - the question)

*Le gané* (I beat him/her - at the game/competition)

To dispel any doubt, under [DPD](https://www.rae.es/dpd/pegar) we can read (the bolds are mine):

> pegar(se). 1. Cuando significa ‘dar [un golpe o una serie de ellos] a alguien’, **es transitivo**; además del complemento directo, lleva un complemento indirecto de persona: «Se volvió el ex boxeador hacia Charo y le pegó dos bofetadas que la tiraron al suelo» (VqzMontalbán Soledad [Esp. 1977]). **A menudo se omite el complemento directo, por quedar implícito o sobrentendido; en ese caso, el complemento de persona, en la lengua culta de la mayor parte del ámbito hispánico, sigue considerándose indirecto**: «No es caso insólito que a un santo cualquiera sus devotos **le** peguen y lo castiguen hasta que acceda al milagro que se le pide» (Ortiz Música [Cuba 1975]). No obstante, en estos casos, es normal que los hablantes de ciertas zonas de España interpreten el complemento de persona como directo: «Nos dijo que su padre **la** pegaba» (País@[Esp.] 9.7.94); este uso, influido además por el régimen del verbo sinónimo golpear, que rige complemento directo de persona, solo se da en zonas laístas (→ laísmo), por lo que **se desaconseja en el habla culta.**

Using "la" or "lo" instead of "le" with the verb "pegar" used to be nonstandard Spanish. Notice above that transitive "pegar" takes "le" while transitive "castigar" takes "lo". Being transitive is not a condition for taking only "lo" or "la".

According to the Tweet mentioned in the other reply, the RAE seems to have reconsidered the case and will decree the grammatical acceptability of "lo" and "la" with the verb "pegar" meaning "hit", although in the expanded version of the response published by ABC Cultura it is acknowledged that this is a minority usage (apparently mostly restricted to Madrid, as it arises from several comments by Twitter users) rejected by many speakers all over the Spanish-speaking world.

To confirm the above, below you can find another Tweet by the RAE which clarifies that both constructions are accepted and that **the one with "le" is the more traditional and widely used**:

[image: Tweet for Lambie]

Comment: The timeline: The first tweet is from April 25. After that, came the one you quote on April 29.  And everything in the second tweet was already in the ABC Cultural article under the first tweet.

Answer (score 1):

The original Tweet from the RAE:

[image: twitter feed]

Then, the response in greater detail:
MADRID Actualizado:29/04/2020 16:54h

> La Real Academia Española (RAE) revisará en la próxima actualización
> del Diccionario panhispánico de dudas la explicación sobre la
> construcción gramatical del verbo "pegar" para dar cuenta de la
> "justificación" de las dos construcciones que admite, tal y como han
> confirmado fuentes de la RAE, tras la polémica suscitada en Twitter a
> raíz de una respuesta sobre el uso de pronombres con este verbo.
>
> Según han aclarado fuentes de la institución, la respuesta que se ha
> dado en el tuit que ha suscitado la polémica tiene que ver con el
> verbo pegar y "no supone en ningún caso una reconsideración de la
> norma académica en relación con el laísmo".
>
> Dos construcciones En concreto, el servicio de dudas de la RAE ha
> señalado en Twitter que **el verbo "pegar" admite dos construcciones,**
> que se corresponden con "dos acepciones" distintas del verbo
> registradas tanto en el diccionario académico como en otros
> diccionarios de español. Por un lado, la Academia alude al verbo
> "pegar" como sinónimo de "dar un golpe (complemento directo) a alguien
> (complemento indirecto)". En este caso, cuando aparecen los dos
> complementos, el de persona es siempre indirecto y es, por tanto,
> "laísmo censurable" la construcción: "La pegó un golpe".

> Por otro lado, en el caso del verbo "pegar" entendido como "maltratar
> a alguien (complemento directo) con golpes", el complemento de persona
> se interpreta como "complemento directo" y el verbo admite, por ello,
> pronombres de acusativo con referente de persona. Por este motivo, la
> construcción "la pegó" (o "lo pegó"), aunque es "minoritaria y
> rechazada por muchos hablantes", está "gramaticalmente justificada".
> Tal y como explica la RAE, esta doble posibilidad es análoga a la que
> presentan otros muchos verbos, como es el caso de "perdonar".

```
                      ***** *****
```

[ABC CULTURA](https://www.abc.es/cultura/abci-explica-cuando-pego-no-laismo-202004291648_noticia.html?ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F)

**Conclusion**: La pegó. is grammatical and Le pegó. is what many people say.